# Choosing constants so the differential equation is homogeneous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Hello I'm having trouble with this problem from the book Differential equations with applications and historical notes by George Finlay Simmons:

> If $ae ≠ bd$, show that constants $h$ and $k$ can be chosen in such a way that the substitutions $x=z − h$, $y=w − k$ reduce \begin{align} 
> \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=F(\frac{ax+by+c}{dx+ey+f})
> \end{align} to a homogeneous equation.

I don't know how to procced beyond doing the substitution and chosing the constant terms so they cancel 
each other, and in that way the function is homogeneous of degree $0$.

Any insight would be great, thanks.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823709/sustitution-x-z-h-and-y-w-k-reduce-the-differential-equation-fracdydx

Comment: Thanks! Didn't find that one when I was searching.